# aws autoscaling AMI with OSSEC installed

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling, ossec

so we've created an autoscaling group with an ami of our own, that ami have a server and an automated ossec service that reports to slack channel, the thing is that when a new instance is launched, the ossec send a lot of alerts because the files signatures are different and that is ok because when a new instance is launched it recreates the ami in new volumes.

Now how can I have ossec installed in those ami, but when as launch a new instance not having all the alerts from files changed.

I tried restarting ossec service when a new instance is launched but It had the same behavior, ossec sends alerts that all the files were changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this could be using a cronjob or systemd, to restart o start the hybrid OSSEC process.

In my case we decide to add the folders in the exceptions so the OSSEC don't scan that folders.

Answer (score 0):

Since your ossec agent included in your AMI I don't think it is possible to stop these alerts on the first boot, becuase as you said it is simply what ossec does when recognize any change, so I would suggest to do not include ossec agent in the image but alternatively install it using User data whenever auto scale group create a new instance, this may cause extra time to boot the instances but it may fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, and yes I thought about that, so I should install ossec ones the instances is up and running, do you have any example of doing that? Or a code snipet and how should I do that, using code deploy or something else?

Comment: This link maybe heplfull: https://hensonsecuritytools.wordpress.com/2018/04/19/ossec-auto-ossec-automation-in-aws-linux-more-glue/

Comment: Yeah that is if you have a server, I have the auto managed service, so you install the service and grab the configurations and start reporting, I just tried using the user data field when creating an instance from an ami, using both /var/ossec/bin/ossec-control restart and /var/ossec/bin/ossec-control stop start but nothing, ossec still send errors when the EFS is loaded

Answer (score 0):

I have been working to implement ossec under our golden amis in AWS the last days and this has been a huge pain due to the alarms by files changes which generate every time a ec2 instance is created.

Exists two big points here:

1. An ec2 is created using **cloud init**. I had to create a new
   systemd template of ossec service to start after cloud-final.service:

```
              [Unit]
              Description=OSSEC
              After=network.target cloud-final.service
              After=multi-user.target

              [Service]
              Type=forking
              ExecStart=/var/ossec/bin/ossec-control start
              ExecStop=/var/ossec/bin/ossec-control stop
              ExecReload=/var/ossec/bin/ossec-control restart

              Restart=always

              [Install]
              WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. OSSEC work using queues. You have to ensure at the moment you are
   generating the ami the ossec service is stopped and the following
   directories cleaned:

- /var/ossec/queue/diff/local/*
- /var/ossec/queue/syscheck/*
- /var/ossec/logs/alerts/*

I have to do a big effort to achieve that. So I hope that my answer in this post will be helpful in the future